# Random network errors on XPS 13 9360 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, 18.04, xps

My Dell XPS 13 9360 started having random network errors in the last couple of days (firefox, apt updates, everything seems to be affected).

I only use wifi, the problem appears on multiple wifi routers

As far as I can remember, it started after an update couple of days ago.

```
uname -a
Linux mymachinename 4.15.0-47-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP Wed Mar 13 10:44:52 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

dmesg shows a lot of connection loss

```
[ 1020.770922] wlp58s0: Connection to AP 14:91:82:7a:2b:ae lost
[ 1025.784678] wlp58s0: authenticate with 14:91:82:7a:2b:ae
[ 1025.832168] wlp58s0: send auth to 14:91:82:7a:2b:ae (try 1/3)
[ 1025.833814] wlp58s0: authenticated
[ 1025.838891] wlp58s0: associate with 14:91:82:7a:2b:ae (try 1/3)
[ 1025.842646] wlp58s0: RX AssocResp from 14:91:82:7a:2b:ae (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=4)
[ 1025.845821] wlp58s0: associated
[ 1035.107017] wlp58s0: Connection to AP 14:91:82:7a:2b:ae lost
[ 1040.121106] wlp58s0: authenticate with 14:91:82:7a:2b:ae
[ 1040.168512] wlp58s0: send auth to 14:91:82:7a:2b:ae (try 1/3)
[ 1040.170212] wlp58s0: authenticated
[ 1040.174965] wlp58s0: associate with 14:91:82:7a:2b:ae (try 1/3)
[ 1040.179890] wlp58s0: RX AssocResp from 14:91:82:7a:2b:ae (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=4)
[ 1040.182447] wlp58s0: associated
[ 1049.442709] wlp58s0: Connection to AP 14:91:82:7a:2b:ae lost
[ 1054.454300] wlp58s0: authenticate with 14:91:82:7a:2b:ae
[ 1054.501903] wlp58s0: send auth to 14:91:82:7a:2b:ae (try 1/3)
[ 1054.503598] wlp58s0: authenticated
[ 1054.506659] wlp58s0: associate with 14:91:82:7a:2b:ae (try 1/3)
[ 1054.512507] wlp58s0: RX AssocResp from 14:91:82:7a:2b:ae (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=4)
[ 1054.514927] wlp58s0: associated
```

```
sudo lshw -class network
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3a:00.0
       logical name: wlp58s0
       version: 32
       serial: 9c:b6:d0:d4:b4:af
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath10k_pci driverversion=4.15.0-47-generic firmware=WLAN.RM.4.4.1-00079-QCARMSWPZ-1 ip=192.168.1.141 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:133 memory:dc000000-dc1fffff
...
```

```
journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager

ápr 13 22:49:03 xpsbuntu NetworkManager[951]: <warn>  [1555188543.6125] sup-iface[0x55c27a0798b0,wlp58s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
ápr 13 22:49:03 xpsbuntu NetworkManager[951]: <info>  [1555188543.6381] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
ápr 13 22:49:03 xpsbuntu NetworkManager[951]: <info>  [1555188543.7182] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
ápr 13 22:49:08 xpsbuntu NetworkManager[951]: <info>  [1555188548.6132] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
ápr 13 22:49:08 xpsbuntu NetworkManager[951]: <info>  [1555188548.6207] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
ápr 13 22:49:08 xpsbuntu NetworkManager[951]: <info>  [1555188548.6289] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
ápr 13 22:49:08 xpsbuntu NetworkManager[951]: <info>  [1555188548.6356] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
ápr 13 22:49:08 xpsbuntu NetworkManager[951]: <info>  [1555188548.6517] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
ápr 13 22:49:17 xpsbuntu NetworkManager[951]: <warn>  [1555188557.9565] sup-iface[0x55c27a0798b0,wlp58s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
ápr 13 22:49:17 xpsbuntu NetworkManager[951]: <info>  [1555188557.9820] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
ápr 13 22:49:18 xpsbuntu NetworkManager[951]: <info>  [1555188558.0622] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
ápr 13 22:49:22 xpsbuntu NetworkManager[951]: <info>  [1555188562.9579] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
ápr 13 22:49:22 xpsbuntu NetworkManager[951]: <info>  [1555188562.9649] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
ápr 13 22:49:22 xpsbuntu NetworkManager[951]: <info>  [1555188562.9723] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> associated
ápr 13 22:49:22 xpsbuntu NetworkManager[951]: <info>  [1555188562.9794] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
ápr 13 22:49:22 xpsbuntu NetworkManager[951]: <info>  [1555188562.9962] device (wlp58s0): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
ápr 13 22:49:32 xpsbuntu NetworkManager[951]: <warn>  [1555188572.2915] sup-iface[0x55c27a0798b0,wlp58s0]: connection disconnected (reason -4)
```

Comment: Is your router set to auto channel select? Auto 2.4/5 GHz? Auto anything? I suspect that's why the signal is lost.

Comment: Look at the Network Manager logs, not just `dmesg`, with `journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager`. Also `14:91:82:7a:2b:ae` is an IPv6 address - is this intentional?

Comment: Try setting IPv6 to disabled in your wireless connection profile.

Comment: @waltinator: Thanks, added the NM logs. Shows a lot of disconnects too.

Comment: @heynnema: Disabled ipv6 in the wifi network settings. I see no difference so far.

Comment: @chili555: I have disabled the automatic channel setting on the router and this seems to have done something because there ar no more disconnect msgs in the logs and the connection is stable

Comment: I will propose an answer which I hope you will accept if you have found it helpful. Glad it's working!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, frequent discoonections and reconnections are caused by the wireless device having difficulty staying connected when the router is set to auto channel select. I suggest that you tweak the settings in the router.

WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I recommend a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.